# Sitemap generation for Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I'm facing some problem. I want to implement sitemap generation and I'm using [@nuxtjs/sitemap](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/) for sitemap generation but seems like this package currently not support nuxt3 and didn't found solution on internet does anyone know how to implement sitemap for Nuxt3 App.

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module/issues/246 Or you gonna need to make it yourself I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here's the sitemap package for Nuxt-3. It will resolve all the issues and work perfectly with nuxt3
https://nuxt.com/modules/simple-sitemap